# Doubt regarding the proof of "the components of a totally disconnected space are the singleton sets"

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, connectedness

**Totally disconnected spaces** :-
A totally disconnected space is a topological space $X$ in which every pair of distinct points can be seperated i,e. for $x, y \in X, x \neq y$ there exists open sets $A$ and $B$ such that
$X=A \cup B$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.
$A \cap B=\phi$.

**Theorem**

> The components of a totally disconnected space are thes singleton sets.

**Proof** (by my professor):

> Let $x, y \in X$ and $x \neq y$. Consider $Y=\{x, y\}$. If we can show that $Y$ is disconnected then we are done.
> There exists open sets $A$ and $B$ in $X$ s.t.
> $X=A \cup B,\quad x \in A, y \in B, \quad A \cap B=\phi$ $\Rightarrow \quad Y=(Y \cap A) \cup(Y \cap B)$
> containing a pt. is the singleton set containing that pt.

**My doubts**:-

1. Is showing that the two point set $Y$ is disconnected, enough to show that there does not exist any connected set larger than $Y$ which is connected (which in turn shows that components can't be other than singletons).

My doubt arises from the fact that in $\Bbb R$ with usual topology, $\{x,y\}$ is disconnected but that does not mean that components are singletons, in fact component is whole $\Bbb R$ as $\Bbb R$ is connected.

2. Where is the fact $X=A \cup B$ used in the proof? The same proof would have worked even if $X\ne A \cup B$(like in the case of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your professor's reasoning is sloppy at best and, strictly speaking, wrong as your own example with $\Bbb R$ shows. The motivation is roughly correct though. Here is a more careful proof.

Let $x \in X$. Suppose $C \subseteq X$ is any subset containing $x$ such that $\{x\} \subset C$ **strictly**.

We aim to show that $C$ must be disconnected.

Indeed, since $\{x\} \subset C$ strictly, there exists $y \in C$ such that $x \neq y$. So, there exist disjoint open sets $A, B$ of $X$ containing $x, y$ respectively and $X = A \cup B$. Hence, in the subspace topology, $C \cap A$ and $C \cap B$ are open sets of $C$ that are both nonempty since $x \in C \cap A$ and $y \in C \cap B$. Also $C \cap A$ and $C \cap B$ are still disjoint and furthermore $(C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B) = C \cap (A \cup B) = C \cap X = C$. Hence, $C \cap A$ and $C \cap B$ form a disconnection of $C$.

Thus, in conclusion, $\{x\}$ is a maximal connected subset of $X$ i.e. a connected component.

Comment: Thankyou so very much. Now I understand why X =A union B is required. It's needed to show that C = the union of the two open sets in C. And the proof is crystal clear.

Comment: @Esha glad to be of help